# Нужна ли запятая перед "и"? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, ссп, и

***Например, можно написать «Общежитие»(,) и вы увидите специальную плашку, когда будете оформлять заказы в будущем.***

Не удаётся проверить с помощью известных правил. Буду рада не только прямому ответу, но и ссылке на само правило, чтобы запомнить материал.

Comment: Анастасия, а Вы можете пояснить смысл всего предложения? Что-то оно показалось мне нелогичным. А мой ответ теперь под вопросом. По крайней мере он верен для предложения без придаточного с ***когда***.

Comment: Будет ли верен смысл, если переставить придаточное? Тогда запятую не ставим: *Например, когда будете оформлять заказы в будущем, можно написать «Общежитие» и вы увидите специальную плашку*.  Говорю, что-то не так с временем. // И про плашки в общежитии расскажите :))

Comment: К сожалению, формулировку менять нельзя, так как есть необходимость проверить уже имеющиеся предложение, которое нельзя изменить, только отметить его недочёты. Здесь речь о работе приложения, плашка — это название "выпадашки", которую вы часто видите в привычных приложениях на смартфоне)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая перед ***и*** нужна.

***Например, можно написать «Общежитие», и вы увидите специальную плашку, когда будете оформлять заказы в будущем.***

Первое простое предложение – безличное, его основа выражена сочетанием модального слова ***можно*** с инфинитивом ***написать***. Во втором предложении есть и подлежащее, и сказуемое: ***вы увидите***.

[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133) (справочник Розенталя)

> **1.** Запятыми разделяются предикативные части сложносочиненного предложения (простые предложения), между которыми стоят союзы:
> **1)** соединительные союзы ***и, да*** (в значении *и*), ***ни…ни***:
> *Песок блестит на солнце тёплым, жёлтым блеском, **и** на его бархате прозрачные здания подобны тонким вышивкам из белого шёлка* (М. Г.).

Запятая перед союзом ***и*** не ставится, если есть какой-нибудь общий элемент. В данном случае вводное слово ***например*** относится только к первому предложению.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Ваши ответы простые и понятные. Буду погружаться в правило)

Comment: @АнастасияПрокопьева Спасибо и Вам, Анастасия!